# About mapping through several nested functorial levels

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, nested, functor, idioms

A random example: given the following `[Maybe [a]]`,

```hs
x = [Just [1..3], Nothing, Just [9]]
```

I want to map `f = (^2)` through the 3 layers, thus obtaining

```hs
[Just [1,4,9],Nothing,Just [81]]
```

The easiest way to do it seems to be

```hs
(fmap . fmap . fmap) (^2) x
```

where `fmap . fmap . fmap` is like `fmap`, but it goes 3 levels deep.

I suspect that the need for something like this, ***in the general case of composing `fmap` with itself a given number of times***, is not uncommon, so I wonder if there's already something in the standard to compose `fmap` with itself a certain number of times. Or maybe something which "knows" how many times it should compose `fmap` with itself based on the input.

Comment: It is not uncommon, but usually you wouldn't have merely nested functors but a _monad transformer stack_, and that can be mapped with a single `fmap`.

Comment: You can work with [**`Compose`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) to go two (or even more if you cascade) levels deep.

Answer (score 3):

You can work with a [**`Compose`** type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) to go two (or more if you cascade) levels of functors deep.

So we can implement this as:

```
import Data.Functor.Compose(Compose(Compose, getCompose))

fmap (^2) (Compose (Compose [Just [1,4,9],Nothing,Just [81]]))
```

This then yields:

```
Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> fmap (^2) (Compose (Compose [Just [1,4,9],Nothing,Just [81]]))
Compose (Compose [Just [1,16,81],Nothing,Just [6561]])
```

we thus can unwrap it with:

```
Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> (getCompose . getCompose . fmap (^2)) (Compose (Compose [Just [1,4,9],Nothing,Just [81]]))
[Just [1,16,81],Nothing,Just [6561]]
```

By constructing a `Compose` that is a structure that is two `Functor`s deep, we thus make it an instance of `Functor` that combines the two.

Comment: so, `getCompose . getCompose . fmap (^2) . Compose . Compose`, or even `coerce . fmap (^2) . Compose . Compose`, but that's probably not much of an improvement over   the original `fmap . fmap . fmap`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *super* over-engineer this, you can use data kinds and type families.  It's a bit crazy, but consider the following type family:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

type family DT fs x where
  DT '[] x = x
  DT (f ': fs) x = f (DT fs x)
```

Given a type-level list of functors (well, more generally, type function of kind `* -> *`), this wraps up a type in each value of the list.  With this, we can write a crazy type class:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class DMap (fs :: [* -> *]) where
  dmap' :: (a -> b) -> DT fs a -> DT fs b
```

The function `dmap'` takes a function to apply (much like `fmap`) and then transforms this wrapped up `a` into a wrapped up `b`.  The instances for this follow (somewhat) naturally, applying the idea of composing `fmap` with itself as many times as there are functors in the list:

```hs
instance DMap '[] where
  dmap' = id

instance (DMap fs, Functor f) => DMap (f ': fs) where
  dmap' = fmap . dmap' @fs
```

With this, we can write the following:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

x = [Just [1..3], Nothing, Just [9]]
x' = dmap' @'[[], Maybe, []] (^2) x
```

Woohoo!  Well, it's good, but writing out the list of functors is a pain, and shouldn't GHC be able to do that for us?  We can add that by introducing another type family:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat, type (-))

type family FType n a where
  FType 0 a = '[]
  FType n (f a) = f ': FType (n-1) a
```

This type family produces a type-level list of functors from a type that already is wrapped up (using the `Nat` to limit us from going deeper than we may want).  We can then write a proper `dmap` that uses `FType` to solve what the list of functors are:

```hs
dmap :: forall n (fs :: [* -> *]) a b c d. (fs ~ FType n c, fs ~ FType n d, DMap fs, DT fs a ~ c, DT fs b ~ d) => (a -> b) -> c -> d
dmap = dmap' @fs
```

The type signature is a little hairy, but basically it's telling GHC to use the `c` value to determine what the functors are.  In practice, this means we can write:

```hs
x' = dmap @3 (^2) x
```

(Note, I may have left out a language extension or two here or there .)

---

For the record, I don't know if I'd ever use something like this.  The error messages are not great, to say the least, and to advanced Haskellers, seeing `fmap . fmap` (or even `fmap . fmap . fmap`) is not very scary.

Comment: I think you can drop the `Nat` argument from `DT`.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes!  I knew I would need it later for `FType`, and I inadvertently carried it along everywhere.  I've updated the post by removing the `Nat` where possible.

Comment: I'm wondering whether deconstructing the application the way you do in `FType` might harm inference. Sometimes you can improve it by pushing over to the right-hand side. That is, something like `FType n fa = getFun fa ': FType (n-1) (getArg fa)`. That pushes *just a little* information from the `Nat` argument into inference of `c` and `d`. I don't know how practically relevant it is.

Comment: In the above comment, mentally capitalize `GetFun` and `GetArg`. Oops.

Comment: You inspired me to write my own version; I hope you like it.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is inspired by DDub's, but I think it's rather simpler, and it should offer slightly better type inference and probably better type errors. Let's first clear our throats:

```hs
{-# language FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}
{-# language AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# language UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module DMap where
import Data.Kind (Type)
import GHC.TypeNats
```

GHC's built-in `Nat`s are pretty awkward to work with, because we can't pattern match on "not 0". So let's make them just part of the interface, and avoid them in the implementation.

```hs
-- Real unary naturals
data UNat = Z | S UNat

-- Convert 'Nat' to 'UNat' in the obvious way.
type family ToUnary (n :: Nat) where
  ToUnary 0 = 'Z
  ToUnary n = 'S (ToUnary (n - 1))

-- This is just a little wrapper function to deal with the
-- 'Nat'-to-'UNat' business.
dmap :: forall n s t a b. DMap (ToUnary n) s t a b
     => (a -> b) -> s -> t
dmap = dmap' @(ToUnary n)
```

Now that we've gotten the utterly boring part out of the way, the rest turns out to be pretty simple.

```hs
-- @n@ indicates how many 'Functor' layers to peel off @s@
-- and @t@ to reach @a@ and @b@, respectively.
class DMap (n :: UNat) s t a b where
  dmap' :: (a -> b) -> s -> t
```

How do we write the instances? Let's start with the obvious way, and then transform it into a way that will give better inference. The obvious way:

```hs
instance DMap 'Z a b a b where
  dmap' = id

instance (Functor f, DMap n x y a b)
  => DMap ('S n) (f x) (f y) a b where
  dmap' = fmap . dmap' @n
```

The trouble with writing it this way is the usual problem with multi-parameter instance resolution. GHC will only choose the first instance if it sees that the first argument is `'Z` *and* the second and fourth arguments are the same *and* the third and fifth arguments are the same. Similarly, it will only choose the second instance if it sees that the first argument is `'S` *and* the second argument is an application *and* the third argument is an application *and* the constructors applied in the second and third arguments are the same.

We want to choose the right instance *as soon as we know the first argument*. We can do that by simply shifting everything else to the left of the double arrow:

```hs
-- This stays the same.
class DMap (n :: UNat) s t a b where
  dmap' :: (a -> b) -> s -> t

instance (s ~ a, t ~ b) => DMap 'Z s t a b where
  dmap' = id

-- Notice how we're allowed to pull @f@, @x@,
-- and @y@ out of thin air here.
instance (Functor f, fx ~ (f x), fy ~ (f y), DMap n x y a b) 
  => DMap ('S n) fx fy a b where
  dmap' = fmap . dmap' @ n
```

Now, I claimed above that this gives better type inference than DDub's, so I'd better back that up. Let me just pull up `GHCi`:

```
*DMap> :t dmap @3
dmap @3
  :: (Functor f1, Functor f2, Functor f3) =>
     (a -> b) -> f1 (f2 (f3 a)) -> f1 (f2 (f3 b))
```

That's precisely the type of `fmap.fmap.fmap`. Perfect! With DDub's code, I instead get

```
dmap @3
  :: (DMap (FType 3 c), DT (FType 3 c) a ~ c,
      FType 3 (DT (FType 3 c) b) ~ FType 3 c) =>
     (a -> b) -> c -> DT (FType 3 c) b
```

which is ... not so clear. As I mentioned in a comment, this could be fixed, but it adds a bit more complexity to code that is already somewhat complicated.

---

Just for fun, we can pull the same trick with `traverse` and `foldMap`.

```hs
dtraverse :: forall n f s t a b. (DTraverse (ToUnary n) s t a b, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
dtraverse = dtraverse' @(ToUnary n)

class DTraverse (n :: UNat) s t a b where
  dtraverse' :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t

instance (s ~ a, t ~ b) => DTraverse 'Z s t a b where
  dtraverse' = id

instance (Traversable t, tx ~ (t x), ty ~ (t y), DTraverse n x y a b) => DTraverse ('S n) tx ty a b where
  dtraverse' = traverse . dtraverse' @ n

dfoldMap :: forall n m s a. (DFold (ToUnary n) s a, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> s -> m
dfoldMap = dfoldMap' @(ToUnary n)

class DFold (n :: UNat) s a where
  dfoldMap' :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> s -> m

instance s ~ a => DFold 'Z s a where
  dfoldMap' = id

instance (Foldable t, tx ~ (t x), DFold n x a) => DFold ('S n) tx a where
  dfoldMap' = foldMap . dfoldMap' @ n
```

Comment: This is great!  I must say, I feel a little silly for not writing it your way in the first place.

Comment: @DDub, not silly at all. You found a path to a solution. A simpler solution required a path that starts in a different direction.