# Declaring type class instance for composition of constructors

Tags: haskell

In trying to answer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883973/about-mapping-thorught-several-nested-functorial-levels) i wondered:

Suppose I want to be able to write `fmap (+1) [Just 2]` instead of `(fmap.fmap) (+1) [Just 2]` (after all, the composition of two functors is another functor)

I then could try and declare a Functor instance for the composition of `[]` and `Maybe` (i.e. two constructors with kind `* -> *`)

```
instance Functor ..eh??? where 
  fmap f [Nothing] = [Nothing]
  fmap f [] = []
  -- ...etc.
```

However, without a type-level lambda (`\Lambda a -> [Maybe a] :: * -> *`) I don't see how to write the `instance` declaration part:

```
instance Functor Maybe([])
```

is nonsense, and doens't even kind check, of course.

Is there any way around this? Of course, if the constructors happen to be monads (like in this case) I could use monad transformers (i.e. constructors of kind `* -> * -> *` ), and the composition would become an application like `ListT Maybe`, which is perfectly legal. However, that is not the case generally.

Comment: This is not possible, but even if it was, it would not work anway, since there is already a functor for `[]`, so the what functor should be used?

Comment: You can however work with `Compose`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose

Comment: Yes, that would allow `fmap (+1) $ Compose [Just 2]` as `Compose [] Maybe` is a functor instance. However, writing `fmap (+1) [Just 2]` seems natural. Of course, that  would overlap  with the functor instance of `[]`, as Willem van Onsem points out: the compiler would try to typecheck `(+1) (Just 2)` and fail.

Comment: I am probably just another case of the beginner tendency to overestimate the ability of `ghc` to decide overlaps by just failing to typecheck and then try the next possibility. However, `Functor` above could also have been a completely new typeclass, and the question would still stand.

Comment: The GHC constraint resolution algorithm does not work in that way, even if it extends the basic Haskell2010 algorithm. If we have `class C (f :: *->*)` then instances can be defined only on type constructors of kind `k1 -> k2 -> ... -> kn -> * -> *` applied to `n>=0` arguments. No type lambdas allowed, no backtracking in case of failure. Overlapping instances are also mostly disallowed: even with the related extension, the absence of backtracking limits their use.

Comment: Realising that what you want is a type-level lambda is a great insight! In general, for these sort of things you have to use `newtype` as a kludgy boilerplatey type-level function. For example `Compose` can be thought of as a function that takes two `* -> *` types and returns (something isomorphic to) their composition, and then you can make an instance for that. Similarly, you can make your own newtypes to "rearrange" or combine types in a different way, for the purpose of making instances. The wrapping/unwrapping boilerplate on the value level is sometimes annoying though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Data.Functor.Compose` we can write

```
> fmap (+1) $ Compose [Just 2]
=> Compose [Just 3]
```

and further with `coerce`,

```
> coerce . fmap (+1) . Compose $ [Just 2] :: [Maybe Integer]
=> [Just 3]
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but the question (and its title) is not specifically about `Functor`, but about constructors of kind `* -> *` in general

Comment: There is, on the other hand, nothing Functor-specific about the _definition_ of `Compose`, even though its page on Hackage  has "Composition of functors" as a subtitle. So I could define `instance Blurgh (Compose [] Maybe) where...` and then use `blurghmethod $ Compose [Just 2]`.

Comment: and even `coerce . blurghmethod . Compose $ [Just 2]` to get the simple value back. (`coerce` works since `Compose` is a `newtype`).

Comment: @HansLub Rather than using `coerce` directly, you can use [`CoercibleUtils.Newtype.under`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.1.0/docs/CoercibleUtils-Newtype.html#v:under). This will infer the result type without needing additional context. `under Compose (fmap (+1)) [Just 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted and accepted Will Ness's answer. However, it is important to note that, even though `Compose` is a submodule of `Data.Functor` and its Hackage blurb says *Composition of functors*, there is nothing `Functor`-specific about the definition of `Compose`, so the solution will work with any arbitrary type class:

```
class Blurgh f where 
   b : f a -> f a 

instance Blurgh (Compose [] Maybe) where ...

> (coerce . b . Compose)  [Just 2] :: [Maybe Integer]
```